# What is the difference between Manager Leader to Manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

On [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/manage-nodes/#list-nodes) website it is being written:

> The `MANAGER STATUS` column shows node participation in the Raft
>   consensus:
>
> - No value indicates a worker node that does not participate in swarm management.
> - `Leader` means the node is the primary manager node that makes all swarm management and orchestration decisions for the swarm.
> - `Reachable` means the node is a manager node participating in the Raft consensus quorum. If the leader node becomes unavailable, the
>     node is eligible for election as the new leader.
> - `Unavailable` means the node is a manager that can’t communicate with other managers. If a manager node becomes unavailable, you should
>     either join a new manager node to the swarm or promote a worker node
>     to be a manager.

So the manager leader **makes all swarm management and orchestration decisions**.
But what are those **decisions** ?

I can create new service from any of the manager, I don't need to do it from the manager leader.

**UPDATE:**
It was mentioned in [this article](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/raft-logs-on-swarm-mode-1351eff1e690), like @Yunakun mentioned, that everything is going through:

> Among the managers, the **leader** node is the one that logs **all the
>   actions** that are done in the cluster (node added/removed, creation
>   of a service, …). Swarm then ensures that the leader’s logs are
>   replicated within each manager so one of them can take the leader role
>   in case the current one becomes unavailable.

Comment: If no value indicates, is it error ? does it affect the docker swarm operations ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swarm manager nodes use the Raft Consensus Algorithm to manage the swarm state.

Raft is leader-based, which means only the leader node has the ability to change the state of the swarm. If you send a request that requires a state change to a follower node, this request will be forwarded to the leader node.

Those **decisions** are decisions that can change the swarm state, such as, on which node to deploy a new service or should a running service be scaled.

And the decisions are handled internally by Raft. They should be transparent to users.

Comment: from every manager I can decide on which node to deploy a new service just by running: `docker service create --constraint 'node.hostname == worker1'`

Comment: Sure you can. This will be converted to a request and the request will be handled by the leader node.

Comment: Interesting, I tried it and you right. I turn the network off on the manager leader node and second after I send from other manager command to create new service and it didn't succeed. After a new manager leader was elected it succeeded.